# Android ADT Bundle installation issue for ubundu

Tags: android, ubuntu, sdk, installation

I am trying to install android sdk on my ubundu system. I have downloaded and extracted the android sdk with eclipse from developers.android and also downloaded some packages using eclipse Android SDK manager. But when I create a new project which shows lots of errors and it also not showing the layout preview. What should I do now ?

Following are the list of packages I have installed :

```
Tools :-
  Android SDK tools 23.0.2
  Android sdk platform tools 20
  Android sdk build tools 20

Android L( API 20 L preview)
  SDK Platform Android L preview 20 - 1
  ARM EABIv7A system image - 20 - 1

Android 4.4(W API 20)
  SDK Platform 20-1
  Samples for sdk 20-1
  Android wear ARM EABIv7a system image 20-1
  Android wear intel *86 intel system image
  Source for Android sdk

Android 4.4.2
  SDK platform
  ARM EABIv7a system image

Extras
  Android support repository
  Android support library
  Google repository
```

What should I do to make android sdk working ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, ADT doesn't fully support Android Wear out of the box. I encourage you to check out this [blog article](http://blog.benjamin-cabe.com/2014/07/04/how-to-setup-eclipse-for-android-wear-development) where I explain how to properly setup your development environment.

Comment: I am not familiar with android development. So which version will be better for developing mobile applications in ubundu? Is there any useful docs for that ?